# OneToMany relationships taking more database space

Tags: mysql, database-design

We re-factored our user specific configuration from 
`create table user (id, name, ..., config1, config2, config3, ..)` to

```
create table user (id, name, ...);
create table user_config (id, user_id, config_val);
```

Our MySQL database size increased by a factor of 2 after making this change and migrating the users from the older table to the newer table. We made this so that user configuration can be made extensible, but why does the space requirement go up because of this. What could be the reason.

Comment: What does "dramatically" mean exactly?

Comment: Is the database size increase really a problem?

Comment: Yes and I would like to know the reason.

Comment: what kind of numbers are we talking about here - thousands of records? Hundreds of thousands? Millions?

Comment: But then I don't really understand why the increase in size (which I *think* is natural looking at your new structure) is a problem. Aren't we talking about mere megabytes here?

Comment: I don't get your user_config table. Don't you need another field there like config_key? How do you know which settings the user has without any link/key to the setting name? Don't you need key/value pairs like: timeout=120, security=high etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you had an oritinal table with 20 fields, and 1,000,000 users, that would be 20 * 1,000,000 = 20,000,000 items of data.

Say, for example, you now have the same number of users, but decrease the table to 10 fields, and had 10 config rows with three fields each (as per your code). This would be 10 * 1,000,000 + 10 * 3 * 1,000,000 = 50,000,000. This would be a factor of 2.5.

So, basically, for each configuration variable, you are now adding an id (Primary Key), and a user (Foreign Key) field. Added to that, there is now more indexing data that has to be generated.

SO, it could very well be the case that your data requirements have dramatically increased.

Comment: The calculations seem correct - assuming that all fields have the same constant size. Why do you say though that indexing data would be more? You'll actually need bigger indexes but less in number (1 in the new table instead of 10, one for every config column in the old design)

Comment: ypercube: I was assuming that there was one index per record. But, perhaps you are right. I don't know how Sam had setup indexing.